# DEM interpolation when re-projecting

Tags: coordinate-system, dem, interpolation, srtm

Can there be some instances where it is necessary to interpolate DEM when re-projecting (e.g. SRTM from WGS84 to another projection)?

My current understanding of interpolation tells me that one should interpolate a dataset only once (i.e. as SRTM has already been interpolated there is no need to do that again).

I have come across some comments where apparently it has been interpolated (again) when re-projecting. This is just a general question, just want to know if my understanding of interpolation is right or wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a link to at least one of the comments that you have come across?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to give more information about your data and why you need to reproject it?  Why do you think it needs to be interpolated again, and if so how would you expect to do so?

Comment: @Midavalo: I don´t have any data. As I mentioned, this is just a general question. I want to know if I my understanding of interpolation is correct or not. For example, if you would work with SRTM (https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/), and you would reproject it to the projection relevant to your country, would you need to interpolate?

Comment: @mikbet What comments have you come across?  Can you link to them?  Why do you think it needs to be interpolated again, and if so how would you expect to do so? Why would you need to reproject (and not project your data to that of the DEM)?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Could understand some people finding it unclear or broad; but primarily opinion-based?

Comment: Ok, let's rephrase. Imagine I'm gonna take the before mentioned SRTM, cut out DEM for let's say England and reproject to their national projection. Is there anything else that has to be done with this data, e.g. interpolation, before it can be used for analysis purposes?

Comment: @mikbet, this is still a broad question, and not particularly suited to this site as it is. Please [edit] your post rather than ask another question in the comments, so it's visible to more  people.